# Black cover with crystalline spaceship (80s kids scifi)

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this book in the 80s and based a book report on it.  It was a science fiction novel aimed at younger readers with a black(?) dust jacket with a weird kind of *crystalline* spaceship on the cover.

The title may have had either "sun" or "ice" in it and was a short 2-3 word title.

Somewhere within was a scene in a field and a data storage unit that had lost all records due to a catastrophe.

Comment: I've removed the 'chatter' to try to make this easier to read and find your book